# Import text as text in Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to load a large CSV file into Access, since I am joining tables that are too large in Excel, and I've been having issues with Access's "intelligence" (or lack thereof) in the process.

I imported my table and it told me there were 170,000+ errors.

I investigated and I did a **GROUP BY** on the error fields and found they were limited to these columns:

[image]

Opening the CSV in Excel, I found that in "Assignment sequence number", there were some entries with **XX**, but Access had inferred it to be an "Integer" and thus the import failed.

I have to import 25 of these files and there are 60+ fields in each one. Is there a way to automatically have Access treat any field as text if there is text anywhere in that column for any record? Its assumptions are mostly right but these don't make any sense. It's not feasible to run a GROUP BY on every import and then go and scroll through all the fields on a second import and then change all those to text. How can Access do this automatically?

I don't really care if the data types are too lenient at present. I am going to merge a bunch of tables and throw the database away and I'll probably refine the schema at the very end once I've combined all the tables.

Comment: If you're comfortable using the command line you might have more success with SQLite than Access. Unlike most databases, SQLite lets you store any type in any column. Refer to [CSV import](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) and [CSV export](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_export) in the [SQLite CLI documentation](https://sqlite.org/cli.html).

Answer (score 1):

Manually add a new row to the start of each of your 25 files, using dummy values.

By doing this, you get to choose what Access sees first in each column, and hence what data type it infers.

For your purposes, you will simply need to use a character string like "AAA" for each column.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but this would then have text for all columns, not just the ones that already have text. Are you saying Access only looks at the first row to determine datatype?

Comment: @InterLinked tbh I haven't used Access for some time but yes, I believe that's essentially what you were facing when you found that 'there were some entries with XX, but Access had inferred it to be an "Integer" and thus the import failed': Access inferred that because there were integers in the first row, and the entries with XX came later. On the other point, for finer control you could of course use "AAA" in the problem columns only, and use dummy data of a suitable data type in other cols.